# Error getting while extracting hog features from set of images using python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to extract HOG features from set of images But i am getting Memory Error as

```
hists = [np.bincount(b.ravel(), m.ravel(), bin_n) for b, m in zip(bin_cells, mag_cells)]
```

MemoryError

I have copied HOG function from [opencv example](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d3b/tutorial_py_svm_opencv.html#gsc.tab=0) my sample code is

```
def hog(img):
  gx = cv2.Sobel(img, cv2.CV_32F, 1, 0)
  gy = cv2.Sobel(img, cv2.CV_32F, 0, 1)
  mag, ang = cv2.cartToPolar(gx, gy)
  bins = np.int32(bin_n*ang/(2*np.pi))    # quantizing binvalues in (0...16)
  bin_cells = bins[:10,:10], bins[10:,:10], bins[:10,10:], bins[10:,10:]
  mag_cells = mag[:10,:10], mag[10:,:10], mag[:10,10:], mag[10:,10:]
  hists = [np.bincount(b.ravel(), m.ravel(), bin_n) for b, m in zip(bin_cells, mag_cells)]
  hist = np.hstack(hists)     # hist is a 64 bit vector
  return hist
path_url="d:/anto/preimages/"
listdir = os.listdir(path_url)
for file in listdir:
  img = cv2.imread(path_url + file)
  h=hog(img)
```

Comment: what is inside preimages folder?

Comment: @Ceem Only images.I have some random images of animals and buildings downloaded from google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your image set.Since you have downloaded images randomly from google.It may have different sizes and that is causing the Error.Before calling hog function you must resize the image.In opencv you can resize using

```
resized=cv2.resize(img,(250,250))
h=hog(resized)
```

In PIL library you can resize using

```
resolutin=(250.250)
resizes=img.resize(resolution , Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

But i must recommend to add a separate preproceesing step.In the preprocessing step you can resize and save all images in your 'preimages' folder to another folder and you can give this as input to your hog extraction program.